# Know if I buy a compatible hardware

Tags: hardware, cpu, compatibility, motherboard

I want to buy a Micro Core I5 3340
Mother Gigabyte GA H61M S1
DDR3 4GB RAM
1TB WD SATA 3 16mb

This hardware, will be compatible with ubuntu 14.04 and further?
Thanks for help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it definitely will be compatible. In fact, I doubt there is a PC motherboard that is not able to run Linux. Sure, in some cases some onboard hardware might not work out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

[DELL Inspiron 660MT 18.5 Inch Desktop PC (Intel Core i5-3340)](http://www.anugrahpratama.com/product/dell-inspiron-660mt-185-inch-desktop-pc-intel-core-i5-3340/)

[Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/)

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is preferable to put more than just links as an answer and provide some details.

Comment: I check the links, thanks you! When I search in Google I didn't see that results. Thanks you!